# searching files containing a string in filename in batch

Tags: batch-file

I'm attempting to search a certain directory for a certain file.

```
dir *test*.txt /s /b
```

This works, and successfully finds the file "0x0test0x0.txt", but only if the file is located within the current directory. 
I attempted to search the whole drive, which is my original intention;

```
dir C:\ *test*.txt /s /b
```

This does search the entire (C:) drive, but not only the files that have "test" in their filenames.

It would be great if i could search the entire (C:) drive for files with a specific string in their filename, and only return the path for the files with the string in their filename.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dir` can take more than one filemask.

```
dir C:\ *test*.txt /s /b
```

lists all files in C:\ and in below folders AND `*.test*.txt` in the current folder.

Get rid of the space:

```
dir C:\*test*.txt /s /b
```